# Constraint diophantine equations (open problem)

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, open-problem

Given an odd number $N$ such that $N\equiv 3 \mod 4$, I am looking to find numerically or algebraically a positive natural number $k$ s.t, $1\leqslant k \leqslant \frac{N-3}{4}$, satisfying the quadratic equation:
\begin{equation}\label{e1}
(a+1)^2=2(N+1)-4k-b
\end{equation}
Where $a$ & $b$ are defined by
$$a=\frac{N-3}{4}-3(k+1)+m$$
$$b=16k^2+(40-4m)k-m(N+5)+24$$
And 
$$m=\left\lfloor\frac{(4k+5)^2-1}{4k+5+N}\right\rfloor$$
under the constraint which are
$$5k-m=\left\lceil\frac{(5k-m)^2+4kN-\frac{N^2-30N+609}{16}}{10k-2m+\frac{N+25}{2}}\right\rceil , \quad \mbox{prime factors of $N$ are unknown}$$
Where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\lceil x \rceil$ denotes respectively the floor function and the ceil function of the real number $x$.
If the given odd number $N$ is small enough, I can find the solution to this problem without knowing its prime factors. The problem is when $N$ is taken big enough. The brute force algorithm is usless, and factorization can take ages!!

Comment: Welcome to math.se.  On the face of it this is an arbitrary and unmotivated problem.  If you could give some brief explanation of why it is actually an interesting problem, you would probably get more people thinking about it.

Comment: This looks extremely complicated. Why do you expect that a nice solution exists ?